# How to find the name/id of the custom list template that is used to create a list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, template, list-template

I have created SP survey and saved it as template.Then I created a survey using that template.I was able to find that template belongs to Survey through (g_wsaListTemplateId = 102).But I din't get any reference to identify the name or id of the custom template that I have used.

Can anyone help me finding out the name of the custom template used to create that list?

Thanks!!

Comment: Using what?? JS or C#?

Comment: I created in site itself .SiteContents->Add an app->Survey. By going to SurvEdit.aspx of that survey I used "Save as template" option.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do via 
Exporting List Schema via export list command.

To export List Schema follow below url:

https://yourdomain.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={ListGuid}

where {ListGuid} corresponds to the List Guid

To find out you List Guid go to List - List Settings and copy List Guid from URL 
ideally it would be with query strin name "List={guid}"

In the generated List Schema you will find ServerTemplate that corresponds to List Template ID

Comment: I followed it.I got a xml file auto generated.How can I import that into another site collection?

Comment: use this file to find template id..... open this xml file and you will find ServerTemplate that corresponds to List Template ID